# Permission error with Classview extending ViewSet, how can I add permissions to non model viewset?

Tags: python, django, rest, permissions, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a set of endpoints that are not related to models in Django. I am using Oauth2 for authentification and I am getting all the time 403 error asking for missing permissions.

How can I know which permission I am missing for this endpoint?

I have tried with *permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]* but it didn't work

```python
class RealTimeMonitoringViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet, NoModelBaseViewSet):

extra_serializers = {
    "transcoding": serializers.RealTimeTranscodeSerializer,
}

@list_route(methods=["get"])
def transcoding(self, request):

    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

    if request.user.userprofile.isKmhAdmin:
        data = get_queue()
    else:
        data = get_queue(request.user.userprofile.selectedClientId)

    for jobqueue in data:
        try:
            if jobqueue['state'] != 'finished':
                jobqueue['start_time'] = datetime.now()
                jobqueue['end_time'] = datetime.now()
                jobqueue['run_time'] = '0 min 0 sec'
            jobqueue['file_name'] = Object.objects.get(pk=jobqueue.get('object_id')).name
        except Object.DoesNotExist:
            Log.exception("Transcode is returning an Object with {pk} that doesn't exist ".format(pk=jobqueue.get('object_id')))

    serializer = serializers.RealTimeTranscodeSerializer(data=data, many=True)

    if not serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    return Response(data=serializer.data)

class NoModelBaseViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):

authentication_classes = [OAuth2Authentication, SessionAuthentication]
pagination_class = pagination.PageNumberPagination
filter_backends = (
    filters.OrderingFilter,
    DjangoFilterBackend,
    filters.SearchFilter,
)

extra_serializers = None
"""
    Look for serializer class in self.extra_serializers, which
    should be a dict mapping action name (key) to serializer class (value),
    i.e.:

    class MyViewSet(BaseViewSet, ViewSet):
        serializer_class = MyDefaultSerializer
        extra_serializers = {
           'list': MyListSerializer,
           'my_action': MyActionSerializer,
        }

        @action
        def my_action:
            ...

    If there's no entry for that action then just fallback to the regular
    get_serializer_class lookup: self.serializer_class, DefaultSerializer.

    """
extra_model_permissions = None

def get_serializer_class(self):
    default_serializer_class = super(NoModelBaseViewSet, self).get_serializer_class()
    if self.extra_serializers is None:
        return default_serializer_class
    return self.extra_serializers.get(self.action, default_serializer_class)
```

Comment: "it didn't work" does give zero clue to help you. Permissions do work with non model view sets but there's not enough context about what you expect and how you saw it does not work.

Comment: As I said on the beginning, the response is returning 403, that's the error. And I am expecting to receive a 200.